# List values replace is not working as expected

Tags: python, list

For below code

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in L:
    L[i] = 2
print(L)
```

I expected the result to be `[1, 2, 2, 2, 2]`

But received `[1, 2, 2, 4, 2]`, why?

Comment: Add `print(i, L)` inside the loop and you'll see for yourself.

Comment: Pencil & paper time. :) Just write out the values of the array at the end of each iteration.

Comment: No, because if you change element on position 2 to 2, then this setting will always be made `L[2] = 2`

Comment: Could you please edit your question: (1) to make it have a more concrete title; (2) to include an explanation of _why_ you're expecting things to behave differently.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list (`L`) values are changing *while* you're looping, so you're not accessing values `1`, `2`, `3`, etc..., but rather different values.

If you break down each iteration, it may become clearer

First iteration:
`i = 1` (the first value in `L`), `L` updates index `1` to be 2 (so no changes):

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Second iteration:
`i = 2` (the second value in `L`), `L` updates index `2` to be 2:

```
L = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5]
```

Third iteration:
`i = 2` (the now third value in `L`), `L` updates index `2` to be 2 (so no changes):

```
L = [1, 2, 2, 4, 5]
```

Fourth iteration:
`i = 4` (the fourth value in `L`), `L` updates index `4` to be 2:

```
L = [1, 2, 2, 4, 2]
```

Fith/Last Iteration:

`i = 4` (the new fith value in `L`), `L` updates index `4` to be 2 (so no changes):

```
L = [1, 2, 2, 4, 2]
```

Thus, your resulting list is the following:

```
[1, 2, 2, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Wonderful explanation! This makes perfectly sense to me now. I was not considering that the third value in the list is 2 after the change. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to do `L[i]` after `for i in L`. Why?

- `i` represents an item in this list not the index of this list.

In your loop, you are using each item as an index to L to replace their value with 2.

Why `4` is in `[1, 2, 2, 4, 2]`?

- The index number of item `4` is `3`.

**Proof**

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> for i in L:
...     print(id(i))
...
4436993456
4436993488
4436993520
4436993552
4436993584
>>> for i in L:
...     L[i] = 2
...
>>> for i in L:
...     print(id(i))
...
4436993456
4436993488
4436993488
4436993552
4436993488
>>>
```

- `id` to find `Return the identity of an object`
- You can also see `4436993488` is found multiple times in this second list. This show where your replace is done.
- This 3 in the list got replaced by 2, just this `4` had a chance to get replaced. So `L[4]` never occured !!

Answer (score -1):

```
for i in L:
```

This iterates over the **values** in the list; i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc.

But you are using those values as indexes into the list. So the result is not what you expect. 
You're basically doing:

```
L[1] = 2
L[2] = 2
...
```

You probably want:

```
for i in range(len(L)):
```

Comment: Yes I am using list values as indexes, but I don’t understand why L[3] is 4 and not 2. If I’m not wrong the loop should be like this: L[1] = 2 L[2] = 2 L[3] = 2  L[4] = 2

Comment: Since you're setting every value to `2` you never get to `L[3]` so it stays unmodified. You're always changing `L[1]`, `L[2]` or `L[4]`